# In a stored procedure running on server A, is it faster to join a table on server B to a table on server A or to the same table on server B?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am working on building a data store database in SQL Server for reporting purposes. Let's call this server A. I am creating scripts that will pull in the necessary data from several linked servers (B and C). I am trying to make them as performant as possible.

I have one script that pulls data using a complex query with many joins, but all from tables on server B. I already have some of the data required for these joins on server A from a previous load script.

So here is my question - which is faster:

1. Join the tables on server B to the tables which have the required data on server A
2. Just do all the joins on server B

I think number 2 would be faster, but I know that doing things over the network via linked servers is slower, so I am not sure.

Comment: (1) There's no right answer to this question, because it depends on a lot of factors. (2) Did you try it? You're in the best possible position to test joining your data between your servers over your network and measuring the performance aspects you care about (probably speed, but that's hardly the only one).

Answer (score 1):

Remote joins are *typically* much slower than local joins.  So you should try rather hard to only join tables in one place.

To join all the tables on B and return the results to A run a "passthrough" query on B using [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or `EXEC(@sql) at B`.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Openquery, I will look into this, it sounds promising!